# Do cache cleaner (or "phone booster") apps actually work?

Tags: applications

Do apps that *clean junk files actually work?* For example, an app like [Super Cleaner.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hawk.clean.spaceplus)

It promises to clean **residual files** and **junk files**.

My main debate is similar to "*Does Android need an antivirus?"* I can tell that some cleaners make my phone seemingly fast, I just don't know if it's needed, funcitonal or even safe. I've heard that some delete important files, while some don't.

Comment: It's peculiar that you accept an answer which doesn't even try to answer your question, namely - do "phone booster" actually work (whatever you mean by that).

Comment: He did answer the question. Did you even read the answer? "I can say, in my experience that it is truly contingent on the tool you choose to use." Time for due diligence. He not only said that, but linked an app that he uses that essentially, on its own from reading the info, answers the question for me. He provided lots of details. What did I mean by that? When I say work, I mean function. When I say "phone boosters", I mean apps that claim they "boost your phone." Simple as that. Nothing hard to understand here. Thank you for your input! :-) The answer helped me, so that's that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can say, in my experience that it is truly contingent on the tool you choose to use.

I am very happy with [SDMaid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.thedarken.sdm), which i have used for years. It seems to clean everything it says it will.

If you read through my other postings here, you will find I usually recommend it for the "CorpseFinder" functionality to clear remnants of older, non-fully uninstalled apps, though the AppControl, SystemCleaner, and Databases functionality are useful, too.

I am satisfied each time I use it that the cleared item were non-critical, yielding back space I can use. I have not encountered a problem with either my phone, or my tablets, where files were improperly deleted, that I would attribute to some actions of this software.

DISCLAIMER - I am not the developer, or attached to the product in any way, except as a satisfied user.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I'll try it out. Just curious: why is it called "SD" Maid when it doesn't necessarily have to do with the SD Card? Unless I'm being totally silly and am missing something?

Comment: @MikeKuplevatsky - I have no idea, and their Help doesn't explain the name. The Help has all kinds of contact avenues, maybe they'll share if you ask them.